# php: get option select value by mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

I'm trying to have an altas.php file for various html forms. This code is a html form with some mysql columns:

```
<div><label for="categoria">Categoría principal</label><select type="text" name="categoria">
        <?php 
            $query = "select id, categoria from categorias";
            $result = mysqli_query($mysql,$query);
            if(!$result) echo 'Muy mal....';
            $num_filas = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $num_filas; $i++){
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        ?>
        <option value "<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['categoria']?></option><?php
            }   
        ?>
        </select></div>
```

On the other hand, if I make this:

```
foreach($_POST as $campo => $valor){
        echo $campo ." = ". $valor ."\n";
    }
```

I have no data in `$row['categoria']`. It should return the value, which is the categorias's id.

Another question:

How can I use the "foreach" whith an insert sentence?

For example:

```
 foreach($_POST as $campo => $valor){
$query ="INSERT INTO $tabla ($campo) VALUES ('$valor')";
}
```

$tabla is sent via $_GET. This code make a new row for each $campo. Any idea?

I have try some suggestions, but nothing works.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: is that `<select>` inside your `<form>`? if it's not, then the browser doesn't have to submit it with the rest of the form.

Comment: Added some boldness I see @tadman ;-) that'll surely get 'em.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - we can but hope

Comment: @andrewsi Best to catch 'em right at the gate; as it were ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm sure it's super annoying but that's the intention here. This sort of stuff is still out of control.

Comment: @tadman Not annoying for me. They need to know and to pass it on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing an = and closing semi-colons on this line:

```
<option value "<?php echo $row['id']?>"><?php echo $row['categoria']?></option><?php
```

Should be:

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['categoria']; ?></option><?php
```

**EDIT:**
Also removed type from select list

Comment: Thanks, but it still not working. Also I changed the type of the select for "number", but... nothing!

Comment: Take the type attribute off of the select, it does not need it

Comment: Excellent, i have updated my answer, could you mark mine as the correct answer please. Glad we got it working